# Spring boot not able to autowire

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, autowired

I have a java library which is having a interface (`IConfig`)and the interface is implemented(`Config`) inside my spring boot application which is having a dependency to the library.

Now from my application I am calling a function of the library which is autowiring the interface and calling one of its function as follows:

```
@Autowired
IConfig conf;
```

My goal is when I will call `conf.getItem()` from the library my implementation in spring boot application (`Config.getItem()`)should get called. But it is not getting autowired properly and giving `NullPointer`.

Please help.

Comment: share the code which you have tried

Comment: Have you annotated your implementation? Is your componentscan working well?

Comment: Not enough information to provide solution but things to check; is the auto package scanning setup correctly? Where/how is the `Config` bean defined?